# trying to fetch a single product and display it in a component but it's not working, I'm having a Service an a component to show this data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, service, navigation

**frisur-details.component.ts**

> hier am trying to fetch a single data and display it
> in this detail-component

```
  frisur: Frisur;
  subs: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private service: FrisurService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subs = this.service.getFrisur(this.route.snapshot.params['id'])
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.frisur = res
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.subs.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**frisur.service.ts**

> the service to fetch a list of data
> and a single data

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FrisurService {
  private apiUrl = './assets/frisur.json'
  frisure: Frisur[];
  frisur: Frisur;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getFrisurList(): Observable<Frisur[]> {
    return this.http.get<Frisur[]>(this.apiUrl);
  }

   getFrisur(id: number){
     return this.http
      .get<Frisur>( `${this.apiUrl}/${id}` )
       .pipe(
           map(res => this.frisur = res)
       )
   }
}
```

**frisur-detail.component.html**

> i'm getting a 404 Error Not found

```html
<div class="container container1" *ngIf="frisur">
  <div class="innen-div">
    <div><img class="image-div" src='{{frisur.avatar}}'></div>
    <p class="spacer mat-body-1"><b>{{ frisur.style }}</b></p>
    <p class="spacer mat-body-1">{{ frisur.model }}</p>
    <a mat-stroked-button color="primary" routerLink="/">Go Back</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the response exactly but I'm assuming that you get something like this

```js
// response from the API.
{
  id: 1,
  avatar: 'imageurl.png',
  style: 'string',
  model: 'string'
}
```

First, edit your service so it can return the response as it is.

in your `getFrisur()` method in `frisur.service.ts`

```js
getFrisur(id: number){
    return this.http.get<Frisur>(`${this.apiUrl}/${id}`);
}
```

Also, another thing is in your `html component`
instead of this

```html
<img class="image-div" src='{{frisur.avatar}}'>
```

Replace it with

```html
<img class="image-div" [src]="frisur.avatar">
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, 
I've edited the function to fetch a sinle Frisur-Object as you mention but it's still not working
that is the error i'm getting:

GET http://localhost:4500/assets/frisur.json/1 404 (Not Found)

ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4500/assets/frisur.json/1", ok: false, …}

Comment: Here you go, [see this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-y4egxd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I don't know if you still having this issue or not. But I've just noticed that you are fetching from a JSON file which you cannot fetch a single entry from a JSON file.

What you can do is to fetch the JSON file entirely and then write a method to filter over the returned response to get a single entry 

**CODE** 

```js

function fetchSingle(id: number) {
  return this.response.filter(entry => entry.id === id);
}
```
Sorry again.